# Website in middle, when you zoom doesn't change it's look

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, web

Hi can you hlp me solve my problem? I want to do website that is in the middle of webbrowser and when you zoom, it doesn't zoom in left upper corner, but it zooms int the middle where the body of the website is. For example like Blizzard's Starcraft website: http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/.
THX

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you mean on a mobile device or desktop? Pinch to zoom or selecting zoom from desktop browser menu? Example of each type of site? What have you tried? Please add your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site basically consists of a background image that is centered.
So all you need to do is create the page in your favourite paint program.

```css
html {height:100%}
body {
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/1500) 50% top no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: but I'd like to ask you again. How do you actualy position elements in this kind of page so they stay allways on their playe. thanks

Comment: Sorry, that's a bit unclear. Are you saying you don't want some things on the page to zoom? Or that you have elements on the page (which are not part of the background image) that you want to keep their position relatively to the image? In any case, it may be best to ask a new question.